# Add functions to PHP language in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code when editing a PHP file the editor color-codes the names of functions that it recognises (eg all the MySQL functions such as `mysql_num_rows()` gets their own color). I'm (finally!) making the switch from the mysql_... functions to the mysqli_... functions and I've noticed that while most mysqli_... functions are color-coded the `mysqli_num_rows()` function isn't, it just shows up as black in the editor instead of being the same color as all the other mysqli_... functions.

I'm assuming that the VSC guys simply overlooked the `mysqli_num_rows()` function when they built the PHP language file for the editor.

I've got no idea how VSC handles languages, is there any way I can edit something so that `mysqli_num_rows()` is included with all the other PHP functions for color-coding? Or would this have to be changed by the VSC guys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add intellisense for removed mysql\_\* functions in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537146/how-to-add-intellisense-for-removed-mysql-functions-in-vs-code)

Comment: Three things: 1. Why are you using `mysqli_num_rows()`? 2. Why are you using the procedural style? 3. Why are you using mysqli instead of PDO?